# You have an error in your SQL syntax; near 'Type='1'' at line 1 - I cant write correct SQL query

Tags: java, sql

I have created a SQL login system in java but want and what to only allow people with account type 1 to access the program. The query I have written keeps coming up as errors. THE SECURITY OF THE PROGRAM IS NOT A CONCERN AS ITS JUST FOR COURSEWORK

```
public void login(){
        try{
            int a = 0;
            int b =1;

            String query ="select * from Users where Login = '"+ 
main_menu.login_text.getText()+"' and Password='" 
+main_menu.passwordtext.getText().toString()+"' and Account Type='" +1+ 
"'" ;
            rs =st.executeQuery(query);
            System.out.println("Records from Database");
            if(rs.next()){
                f=2;

                query ="select * from Users where Login = '"+ 
main_menu.login_text.getText()+"' and Password='" 
+main_menu.passwordtext.getText().toString()+"' and Account Type='" +0+ 
"'" ;
                rs =st.executeQuery(query);
                System.out.println("Records from Database");
                }

            else if (rs.next()){
                f=1;
            }
            else{

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect Username 
and Password...");
            con.close();}



        } catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Error"+ex);
        }
```

Comment: For the record: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection

Comment: `Account Type` should probably be `AccountType`

Comment: change account type in query or database?

Comment: Watch out for Bobby Tables.

Comment: watch out for `Account Type` there's a space in between, try to verify from your DB table that what is your filed name exactly.

Answer (score 0):

As @luk2302 have suggested, you should change your code. With that code, you allow to be easily breach your security.

Here is an example of how to make it better:

```
PreparedStatement pst = null;
String sql = "SELECT * FROM login where username=? and password=?";
pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1,user);
pst.setString(2,pass);
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
```

Now you can just get the data you just recovered to get the information about the user. If no resul set is given, the login would have failed.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: how does this take into account the 'account type'. In all honesty security is not an issue as its just for coursework

Comment: True. I'm sorry. Kind of new, still learning. I just should point the error and no comment in the security breack? Or should I do both? You could change the query to `String sql = "SELECT * FROM login where username=? and password=? and and AccountType=?";` and add `pst.setString(3,1);` to the code.

Comment: As pointed by @Eran, The AccounType should be together in the name of the DB? If not, try using '"Account Type"' instead. When writing sentences, a spaces are not considerate part of a name.